# Load one template into a another one in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

Within one of my route's `renderTemplate` method, I've tried to render a different template by using `this.render`:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function() {

        this.render( 'dashboard', {
            into: 'admin'
        });

    }

});
```

But the application within the browser is empty and the console shows the following:

> Assertion Failed: You attempted to render into 'admin' but it was not
>   found

After this error message, I thought that the "admin" template might simply not be existent, but it it's there. Both the "dashboard" and the "admin" template are loaded. And the weirdest thing: I'm able to use `this.render( 'dashboard' )` and `this.render( 'admin' )` and both of them work fine.

What am I doing wrong? I've even added an `{{outlet}}` tag to the "admin" template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render into `admin` then you have to use named outled inside your template (associated with route file you write `renderTemplate`). So, inside your template use:

```
{{outlet 'admin'}}
```

## edit

> I'm not really sure what to do right now. Just to clarify: "admin" is
>   a hbs template which contains a {{outlet}}. And into this outlet tag,
>   I want to load 'dashboard.hbs'. And after that, I want to output the
>   whole thing.So in which file do I need

I'm assuming you want to render these 2 templates from another unassociated route. In that case you could add `{{partial 'dashboard'}}` to `admin.hbs` and use just `this.render('admin')` in your `IndexRoute`.

## edit 2

Inside your `IndexController` specify `partialName: 'dashboard'` and change it dynamically in your code and replace `{{partial 'dashboard'}}` with `{{partial partialName}}`. It should work dynamically and you can swap out `dashboard` for another templates.

Comment: That you for your help! But I'm not really sure what to do right now. Just to clarify: "admin" is a hbs template which contains a `{{outlet}}`. And into this outlet tag, I want to load 'dashboard.hbs'. And after that, I want to output the whole thing.

So in which file do I need to add your suggestion? :)

Comment: In which route do you want to render these templates?

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer. Using a partial is a great idea and I would have done it like that already if there wasn't this small problem: I need to be able to swap out the template that is being loaded into "admin.hbs" and therefore I'm not able to use partials. Because using a partial would mean that "admin.hbs" will always only contain "dashboard.hbs", but that's not the case. The "admin" template needs to be able to contain other templates as well... :)

Comment: Okay, so inside your `IndexController` specify `partialName: 'dashboard'` and change it dynamically in your code and replace `{{partial 'dashboard'}}` with `{{partial partialName}}`. It should work dynamically and you can swap out `dashboard` for another templates.

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! Thank you very much! :)